# Question about mass growth rate for individual planetesimals

Tags: astrophysics

In one stage of classic accretion, the mass growth rate with time (dm/dt) for individual planetesimals is proportional to $m^{2/3}$ and in another stage it is proportional to $m^{4/3}$.
My question is why are the exponents different? Which stage is a runaway and which stage comes first?

Comment: There are different theories of planetesimal formation - can you clarify where you are finding these relations, and more about what that source says about what the different stages are?

Comment: Some superficial knowledge of differentiation is sufficient to conclude that solutions blow up in finite time for *m* in the 4/3 power and grow indefinitely as time cubed for *m* in the 2/3 power.